# Error command : heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web, migration, production

I have a simply app with rails 3.2.8 and MySQL in development, when I try to use this command > heroku run rake db:migrate I have this error : 
  **PG::Error: ERROR:  column "name" of relation "users" already exists
  : ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "name" character varying(255)**

here is my schema.rb

http://pastie.org/5132185

I don't know how to do, to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You setup the production database correctly in the Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

But you also have the gem included in all environments due to line 14:

```
gem 'pg'
```

You should specify that mysql is a dev/test only gem:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql'
end
```

As for your error, it sounds like the column name already exists on the users table.  Did another migration add that column?

Comment: Well, if you could see my migrates : https://github.com/lccezinha/rails3-twitter-bootstrap/tree/master/db/migrate ,  there is no other migration adding the column 'name' in my table/model User, if I run this migrations in my dev/test  , they run well.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku using only PostgreSql, so you have to change in your gemfile from mysql to PG, or use mysql only for test/local and PG for production

```
gem 'PG' :group => :production
```

Comment: in my Gemfile I have this > 
  group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
  end >

but still doesn't work.

Comment: well you have gem 'mysql2' and then gem 'pg'. You have to specify only 1 database gem, or specify groups for your gems, e.g test\development for mysql2, and pg for production